# Folder Action to Convert Image Format after AirDrop?

Tags: automator, airdrop, folder-action

I often use AirDrop to move photos from my iPhone to my Mac, and I'd like to automatically convert any HEIC photos to JPEG. I created this folder action in Automator, and it works when a photo is dragged into the Downloads folder but not when it has arrived via AirDrop. Is there a trick to getting folder actions to work with AirDropped files?

[image: screenshot of folder action]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, though the conversion is from jpeg as I have an oldish iPhone :(

I have added lots of notifications to confirm each step - simple debugging!

[image]

The pause is a hint I got sometime ago for AirDrop.  Your Get Selected Finder Items is either unneeded or wrong (not sure which).

Comment: It works! Thanks, you're a peach. I had tried a pause but it wasn't long enough. And you're right about the "Get" action—I tried that because I noticed it in a different AirDrop-related folder action but it was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to tweak this a little for me on Sonoma. I made the pause 10 seconds just in case I transfer dozens of files in bulk. And then instead of copying the files, I chose to duplicate the finder items because I wanted to convert them and put them in the same folder (in my case, "Downloads". Usually I'm uploading receipts or silly images for fun online so instead of having to send 3 MB per pic, I do a Scale Images down to 30% of the original size and that makes it around 200 kB usually for my images.

[image: HEIC to JPEG automator screenshot]